# Javascript error when sending XMLHttpRequest in IE7

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have  a bit of a strange problem. For one of my clients I've added some ajax functionality to their website. To get the context; it's a website for a travelagency and pricetables are generates by ajax-calls to reduce serverload and improve user experience.

Only now I received an email where they say it is not working in IE7. So, to test this I first installed IETester but this almost crashes every single time I only open a website. So I've downloaded a trialversion VMWare Workstation and installed a virtual XP machine with IE7 (because IE8 is on my primary Win7 install). What a hassle to simulate an error eh?! ;)

Anyway. After some debugging I think it's the xmlHttpRequest status property, when I try to `alert` this status in the corresponding javascript function IE shows an exclamationsign at the leftbottom corner with some vague 'not further defined error' message while in IE8, FireFox and Chrome this is no problem at all.

So I figured I might have been using the wrong XMLHttpRequest object. But then again, the first call which is also made to intiate the first pricetable for the closest month works just fine. Just to be sure I googled which object should work for IE7, now I'm using `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` and the initial load goes well.

When I click an `<a onclick="callToFunction(with, correct, params)">click</a>` it gets into the function to update a `<div>` but then it sort of freezes. I found out that the `xmlHttp.readyState` is `4` but I can't output the `xmlHttp.status`, then the 'not further defined error' message shows again at the leftbottom corner.

My question after a bit of a long evening trying to solve this, do you guys have any clue what might be the problem?

---

Example:

http://www.bergenmeer.nl/50/oostenrijk/tirol/gerlos/residence-zillertal.html

Click tab 'Prijzen en aanbiedingen' (Prices and special offers) then click another month in the bar below, e.g. jan, feb, maa.

Note, the disfunctioning only appears in IE7.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a demonstration of this issue.

Comment: Updated the question with an URL

Answer (score 1):

In IE7 you could try using [native `window.XMLHttpRequest`](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-on-ie-7-check-native-first).
For  what it's worth, I once had an issue which was resolved by removing `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");` (which I did not see in your code...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this didn't help. +1 for your effort! Do you have other suggestions?